# JMenu leaves a gray box above a JPanel on which image is drawn

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, bufferedimage, jmenu

I am trying to create a menu for my program, which draws some geometric objects on a JPanel using .getGraphics().drawImage(..)

The problem I'm having is that after I select an item on this menu, the text disappears but the background color doesn't. The slection ivokes a method which redraws the image on this panel using the above command, but apparently it doesn't help in removing it.

After I click this menu item and this gray box is left after the menu, I can make it disappear by moving the scene around using my mouse, which basically calls the same method used after the menu item click. This confuses me as to why the menu item method call doesn't remove the box, but next call of this method does.

Any idea on why is this happening and/or how to fix it?

Thank you.

Picture (A, B are JMenus on JMenuBar and the gray box below is left after JRadioButtonMenuItem selection): 
[image: A, B are JMenus on JMenuBar and the gray box below is left after JRadioButtonMenuItem selection]

Comment: My guess is you have blocked the panel from allowing itself to redraw when it detects the menu has disappeared. But I can't tell without seeing code.

Comment: The only thing I manually set on the panel is setPreferredSize(). (Also, all the components are in a JFrame if that makes a difference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> which draws some geometric objects on a JPanel using .getGraphics().drawImage(..)

Don't use `getGraphics()` to do custom painting.

Custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent(...)` method of the `JPanel`. And don't forget to invoke super.paintComponent(...) as the first statement.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: Thank you, that did solve the gray box problem. However, now when the image is re-drawn, it flickers with each redraw, what could be causing that?

Comment: @EyfI, if you have more problems then ask another question that contains a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. Chances are while creating the `MCVE` you will find the problem. Again the point of the tutorial is for you to read the tutorial and download the working example to learn the proper way to code the custom painting. Make sure you follow the code of the tutorial. There is also a tutorial on `How to Use Menus`.